print a formula and assign its result to a variable simultaneously
@wipet gave an excellence solution to calculate a formula and assign its result to a variable . The below syntax partially complete it since  it fails to store the result value. Anyone knows how to improve this code ?
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printandcal}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
   #2 =
    \group_begin:
      \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
      \cs_set:Npn \frac ##1##2 {##1/(##2)}
      \cs_set:Npn \times { * }
      \cs_set:Npn \pi { pi }
      \cs_set:Npn \sqrt ##1 { (##1)**.5 }
      \cs_set:Npx \__cs_tmp:w ##1 { \token_to_str:N ^ (##1) }
      \char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__cs_tmp:w
      \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ } }
        { \l_tmpa_tl }
      \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \exp_args:NNNV \group_end:
   \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } }
   \fp_set:cn  { l_xcn_var_#1_fp } { \l_tmpa_tl } % useless
   % Passing the token list value to mandatory argument #2 ? seems impossible.
   % \fp_set:cn  { l_xcn_var_#1_fp } { #2 } 
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}


$\printandcal{aa}{\pi/2+\sqrt{2}}$ % 

\usefpvar{aa} % the document ouput is 0 , why not 2.985... ?

\end{document}




do not use different number of mandatory arguments, the extra argument is optional so use [] not {}

Well of course, code in questions is not expected to work, while it is possible to have an optional{}  it breaks all latex syntax guidelines and is not advisable

where should I add an optional{} ? the above code with an optional argument may not work.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463626/xparse-g-argument-should-be-avoided

@JosephWright   You are real author of the above code. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454999/calculating-the-value-of-a-formula-without-duplication-using-luatex-or-similar/455016#455016. Is it possible to store the value of  \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } ?

@xcn That's just \fp_set:Nn <some-fp> { \l_tmpa_tl } - but it's nothing to do with the question you've posed here

@JosephWright   well . could you modify the code so that the result value can be stored by a variable for future use ?

@xcn As I've just said, it's a trivial change to the previous post - but not what you asked here. The previous question didn't ask for things to be stored, so it won't really make sense to edit it.

@xcn You seem to be casting around asking arbitrary questions that don't really build on what is already available on the site - the aim of TeX-sx is to build up knowledge that can be reused by many people. I think you really could do to give some sense of what you are trying to achieve, and to understand (La)TeX basics and build up ideas stepwise.

thanks for your advise.

Improving your code is (from my point to view): never using expl3 language. And your problem: you have to use global setting of the value because the setting is done inside math mode, i.e. inside the TeX group. See \xdef primitive in my answer below.

I think you do need to decide what you are trying to learn. If it's TeX primitives, then @wipet is right - but the questions need to be focussed on that but actually be clear. If it's using expl3, then that's also fine (from a site point of view), but again you need to build your understanding of the concepts. At the moment, as I've said if feels like a complete scattergun without any sense of what you are really trying to achieve.

I'd like to learn both of them.

@xcn there's no reason you can't learn both, but I think your questions should make clear which you are trying to learn in that question. if you tag it expl3 and post expl3 code, then you should stick to expl3. if you want to ask about tex primitives, ask about those. if you want to ask about plain, ask about that. it's different if a question is focused on a practical problem: how can I get my header to align with the fifth column of the second matrix on the previous page? then various approaches make sense. but it is hard to figure out what kind of answer you want at the moment.

here, for example, you've posted expl3 code, accepted an answer using core tex and latex 2e, then posted another answer with 'done!' and back to expl3. done what? is that the answer you need? then probably you should accept it (though I don't want to lose wipet a tick.) right now, I don't understand what you are seeking, so it is hard to  suggest where you might search ....

@cfr I replaced 'Done!' with new content.

@xcn I tried to show you that using TeX primitives and simple macros is much more simple that using expl3. This is shown in my examples. Unfortunately I didn't convince you. You are returning to expl3 again and again. IMHO, to learn expl3 and to read expl3 codes is much more complicated. And you must to know dozens of various "commands", "functions", and you have to know TeX primitive behavior too. Without knowledge of this the expl3 is almost unusable.

@wipet You convinced me for your timely and perfect example and showed how powerful TeX primitive and OpTex are. You always know what an answer I am looking for even thought I usually couldn't express my thought clearly in English. The reason why I attracted by expl3 here is that I ever used numerica package for a long time and find a similar macros which makes it interesting to imitate \eval function provided by that package. Since my question is almost solved, I would try to study your example. In fact either TeX primitives or expl3 is difficult for me.

Maybe, you want something like this:
\documentclass{article}

\def\printandcalc#1{\ifmmode #1=\fi
   {\def\sqrt##1{sqrt(##1)}\def\pi{pi}\xdef\tmp{\fpeval{#1}}}%
   \tmp
   \futurelet\next\printandcalcA
}
\def\printandcalcA{\ifx\next\bgroup \expandafter\printandcalcB\fi}
\def\printandcalcB#1{\expandafter\xdef\csname fpvar:#1\endcsname{\tmp}}
\def\usevar#1{\csname fpvar:#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

$\printandcalc{\sqrt{2}+\pi}$ % not store value

$\printandcalc{\sqrt{2}+\pi}{aa}$ % store value to aa

\fpeval{\usevar{aa}+pi}

\end{document}


thanks @wipet . you are so great.

using expl3 to print a formula and assign its result to a variable simultaneously
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printandcal}{mm}
 {
  
   #1 =
    \group_begin:
      \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
      \cs_set:Npn \frac ##1##2 {##1/(##2)}
      \cs_set:Npn \times { * }
      \cs_set:Npn \pi { pi }
      \cs_set:Npn \sqrt ##1 { (##1)**.5 }
      \cs_set:Npe \__cs_tmp:w ##1 { \token_to_str:N ^ (##1) }
      \char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__cs_tmp:w
      \tl_set_rescan:Nne \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ } }
        { \l_tmpa_tl }
      \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \exp_args:NNNV \group_end:
   \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } }
    % \tl_use:N  \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl }
   \fp_zero_new:c { l_xcn_var_#2_fp } 
   \fp_gset:cn  { l_xcn_var_#2_fp } {\tl_use:N  \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } } 
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}


$\printandcal{\pi/2+\sqrt{2}}{aa}$ 

\usefpvar{aa} 

\end{document}


try e instead of x.

@cfr did you mean using \tl_set:Ne instead of \tl_set:Nx ?

the x specifier is deprecated. e is generally recommended. e doesn't prevent further expansion the way x does.

edited already.
